# Some questions on the ring $(\mathbb{F}_3,+,\cdot)$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

1. Find an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3$ of degree 2.

The polynomials to analyse are $9$ in the form:

$X^2+aX+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3$

I find out that the irreducible ones are:

$$X^2+1$$
$$X^2+X+2$$
$$X^2+2X+2$$

2. For the polynomial $p(X)$ found above find the multiplicative inverse to $X+1+p(X)\mathbb{F}_3$ in the quotient ring $(\mathbb{F}_3[X] / p(X)\mathbb{F}_3[X],+,\cdot)$

I pick $p(X)=X^2+1$

$(X+1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle)(aX^2 + bX + c + \langle X^2+1\rangle) = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle  \Rightarrow \\  
\Rightarrow aX^3 + bX^2 + cX + aX^2 + bX + c + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle \Rightarrow  \\
\Rightarrow aX^3 + bX^2 + cX + aX^2 + bX + c + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1 + \langle aX^3+X^2+1\rangle   \Rightarrow  \\
\Rightarrow aX^3+ (a+b)X^2 + (b+c)X + c + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle$

I know that $c=1$ and:
$$a=0\mod3$$
$$a+b=0\mod3$$
$$b+c=0\mod3$$
but I guess there is a mistake :/

3. Is $X+1+p(X)\mathbb{F}_3$ a primitive element of $R=(\mathbb{F}_3[X] / p(X)\mathbb{F}_3[X],+,\cdot)$?

For this point I thought that a primitive element of $R$ should have order $3^2-1=8$ 
Any element of $R$ has an order dividing $8$, that could be $1,2,4,8$.
I just have to check the order of $X+1+p(X)\mathbb{F}_3$, and if it is $8$ therefore it is a primitive element of $R$

Comment: The polynomial $X^2 + 2X + 1 = (X + 1)^2$ is reducible.

Comment: You are right, I mistyped, should be correct now

Answer (score 2):

Your process for finding the multiplicative inverse is wrong. In particular, in the presence of the ideal $\langle X^2+1\rangle$, your implication that $a=0$ (for instance) is completely wrong - for instance, $X^3+X^2+1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1+\langle X^2+1\rangle$.

You're better off first showing that every polynomial in $X$ is equivalent $\pmod{\langle X^2+1\rangle}$ to a polynomial of the form $aX+b$ and then doing the multiplication on that polynomial (using the ideal to reduce appropriately).

Comment: Thanks, that was a huge mistake. I have got it now, thanks.

Comment: $(X+1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle)(aX+b + \langle X^2+1\rangle) = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle  \Rightarrow \\  
\Rightarrow aX^2 + bX + aX + b + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle \Rightarrow  \\
\Rightarrow aX^2+ (a+b)X + b + \langle X^2+1\rangle = 1 + \langle X^2+1\rangle$, then $a=0$? makes no ense again
I would say that $aX^2=0$ (zerodivisor?) and therefore $a=2,b=1$

Comment: @user158013 Remember that you always get to 'mod out' by $X^2+1$, so you should never be comparing any coefficient of $X^2$.  In particular, from $aX^2+bX+aX+b$ you can subtract $a$ times $X^2+1$ to get $bX+aX+b-a$ as an 'equivalent' polynomial (modulo the ideal).